# When upgrading from 32 bit OS to 64 bit OS in Windows XP, is it enough to format C: alone?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, formatting

Currently am using windows XP 32 bit OS with 4 GB RAM. I want to upgrade to 8 GB RAM and I know it needs a 64 bit OS.

I don't want to lose my data, though. So can I install a 64 bit OS by formatting the C drive alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just format drive C: and install your new OS on it. But you know, just your data on drive C:, include Programs, Desktop and Documents will loss. So you should backup the Desktop and Documents on other drives and then do it.

It is better to install 64bit software on your new windows.

Comment: @shgnlnc 'on your new windows' you mean windows 7 or windows 8?

Comment: @Vignesh, Any one you wish?! I mean the new 64bit windows you decide to install.

Comment: All applications will generally need to be re-installed to function properly as well since most of them involve registry settings.

Answer (score 0):

The drive format has nothing to do with the OS bitness, but it's determined by how the OS addresses hardware addresses (memory and drives).
Still, it's a good idea to start a major transition like an OS migration with a cleanly formatted partition. Of course, formatting a partition or drive will erase all files currently there, so if you want to save data, you'll first need to back it up, format the drive, install the new OS and then restore the data.
If you are migrating to Windows 7 64, it has a very nice migration tool that helps migrate the old data just for this type of situation. It will also give a checklist of which applications are compatible or need new versions.